# Como testar um DAO (usando Spring e JPA) fora de um container?

Tags: java, spring, testes-de-unidade, junit

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com JPA 2, Spring e JSF 2 rodando em WildFly 8.0.0. Já desenvolvi algumas aplicações anteriores seguindo essa mesma especificação mas nunca testei devidamente usando jUnit. Agora, eu gostaria de mudar isso e testar mais.

Como eu estou muito no início do desenvolvimento e já quero testar a aplicação, veio o primeiro problema. Como testar minha aplicação com ela rodando **fora de um *container*?** Digo isso porque o *datasource* de minha aplicação é gerenciado pelo container. Logo, estando fora dele não tenho um *datasource*.

Pensei em atribuir a responsabilidade de gerenciar o datasource para o Spring quando eu estiver rodando os testes, mas isso implica em novos arquivos de configurações quando eu estiver rodando os testes. Mais arquivos de configurações significa mais manutenção futura. Eu gostaria de evitar esse cenário, mas se não tiver outro jeito...

Concluíndo e deixando a pergunta, existe alguma forma de testar unitariamente a aplicação fora de um container no que diz respeito ao acesso do datasource?

**EDIT:**
Adicionando algumas informações que podem ser necessárias para a resposta:

Meu datasource (`minhaapp-ds.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema">
    <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/datasource/minhaappds" pool-name="minhaAppDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
        <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@etc:0000</connection-url>
        <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
        <driver>ojdbc6.jar</driver>
        <pool>
            <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>15</max-pool-size>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>minha_app</user-name>
            <password>minha_app</password>
        </security>
        <validation>
            <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
            <background-validation>false</background-validation>
        </validation>
        <timeout>
            <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
        </timeout>
        <statement>
            <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
        </statement>
    </datasource>
</datasources>
```

Meu `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="minhaAppPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/datasource/minhaappds</jta-data-source>

        <class>br.com.cpy.model.Classe1</class>
        <class>br.com.cpy.model.Classe2</class>
        <class>br.com.cpy.model.Classe3</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:jboss/minhaappEMF" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

E finalmente, o `spring-persistence-context.xml`

```
<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:jboss/minhaappEMF" id="entityManagerFactory" expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory" />
<tx:jta-transaction-manager />
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

Answer (score 3):

O único meio de fazer isto é fazer um MOCK do JNDI, como foi postado no Blog do Randy Carver da Oracle.

```
 @BeforeClass
public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    // rcarver - setup the jndi context and the datasource
    try {
        // Create initial context
        System.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
        System.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, 
            "org.apache.naming");            
        InitialContext ic = new InitialContext();

        ic.createSubcontext("java:");
        ic.createSubcontext("java:/datasource");

        // Construct DataSource
        OracleConnectionPoolDataSource ds = new OracleConnectionPoolDataSource();
        ds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:db");
        ds.setUser("MY_USER_NAME");
        ds.setPassword("MY_USER_PASSWORD");

        ic.bind("java:/datasource/minhaappds", ds);
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MyDAOTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Você pode ler melhor a explicação dele em, https://blogs.oracle.com/randystuph/entry/injecting_jndi_datasources_for_junit

Outro ponto importante é o conceito de teste unitário. Isto é abordado muito bem em uma resposta sobre teste unitários com EJB, é uma leitura valida. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6486902/2928776

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas eu estou estudando e pensando em testar usando o Arquillian. Sem usar mocks e testando direto no container. http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/?utm_source=cta